# javascript to check and open page

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to use a form with a single input, that will ask for a 4-letter "secret" code (eg "a123"). The script will check if the corresponding page exists (eg: https://example.com/a123). If it exists, the page opens (in _self). If it does not, an error message is displayed.

The code below does not produce the expected result, it just refreshes the page regardless if my code is a match or not, although the url gets an appended parameter (eg: https://example.com/secret-code/?code=a123).

Functions in head:

```js
function checkUrl(url) {
        var request = false;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                request = new XMLHttpRequest;
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
        }

        if (request) {
                request.open("GET", url);
                if (request.status == 200) { return true; }
        }

        return false;
}

function validateCode() {
    var x = document.forms["secret"]["code"].value;
 if (x == "") {
        document.getElementById("alertmsg").innerHTML = "Enter a code.";
    }
    if (checkUrl("https://www.example.com/" + x)) 
        {
   window.open("https://www.example.com/" + x,"_self");
        } else {
   document.getElementById("alertmsg").innerHTML = "Invalid Code. Try again.";
        }
}
```

Form in body:

```html
<form name="secret" onsubmit="validateCode()">
Code secret : <input type="text" name="code" size="4" maxlength="4" text-transform="uppercase"/>
<div id="alertmsg" style:"color:red;font-weight:bold"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Validate" />
</form>
```

I'm stumped. Thanks for helping me find the issue...

Comment: You have any problem with j query?

Comment: I don't... But I also don't know much about it. Does it go in a <script> html object? I am limited to this at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding another answer.

1. Removed `form` tag.
2. Changed the button type to `button` from `submit`.
3. Added `onclick` event on `button` to call `validateCode()` function.
4. Changed the way to get the secret code value `x`;
5. There was another issue with the blank data (empty string), which should be in the `else` case. Now handled.

```js
function checkUrl(url) {
  var request = false;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest;
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
  }

  if (request) {
    request.open("GET", url);
    request.send();
    if (request.status == 200) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

function validateCode() {
  var x = document.getElementById('code').value;
  if (x == "") {
    document.getElementById("alertmsg").innerHTML = "Enter a code.";
  } else {
    if (checkUrl("https://www.example.com/" + x)) {
      window.open("https://www.example.com/" + x, "_self");
    } else {
      document.getElementById("alertmsg").innerHTML = "Invalid Code. Try again.";
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
Code secret : <input id="code" type="text" name="code" size="4" maxlength="4" text-transform="uppercase" />
<div id="alertmsg" style: "color:red;font-weight:bold"></div>
<input type="button" value="Validate" onclick="validateCode()" />
```

Comment: It worked better. Thanks!
I also had to alter the checkUrl function to nest the return false statement as the else of the if (request.status == 200). Otherwise, it was always returning false.

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes but not tested the code because having `cross` origin problem.

I hope it works for you.

1. Added `return` in `<form name="secret" onsubmit="return validateCode()">`
2. Added `return false;` in `validateCode()` function. As you were facing the page reload problem due to form submission.
3. Added `request.send();`, As you were just setting the to `open` the link, but not sending the request.

```js
function checkUrl(url) {
  var request = false;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest;
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
  }

  if (request) {
    request.open("GET", url);
    request.send();
    if (request.status == 200) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

function validateCode() {
  var x = document.forms["secret"]["code"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    document.getElementById("alertmsg").innerHTML = "Enter a code.";
  }
  if (checkUrl("https://www.example.com/" + x)) {
    window.open("https://www.example.com/" + x, "_self");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("alertmsg").innerHTML = "Invalid Code. Try again.";
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="secret" onsubmit="return validateCode()">
  Code secret : <input type="text" name="code" size="4" maxlength="4" text-transform="uppercase" />
  <div id="alertmsg" style: "color:red;font-weight:bold"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Validate" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks !!
 I did work with your proposed modifications, when I removed the www. from my addresses.   
When I put an invalid code, the url changes from "https://example.com/secretcode/" to "https://example.com/secretcode/?code=a123".
Is there any way to avoid this and leave the url as-is?

Comment: Is it necessary to use the form? that can be implemented without forms